# SendMail on Godaddy

Tags: c#, smtp, sendmail

I've been struggling with getting this syntax right to send mail using Godaddy. Any help would be appreciated. Do I need to add code to my `web.config`?

```
 System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("MygodaddyEmail@asdf.com", "To", "subject ", "body ");
                        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Send(m);
```

The error message is this:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   173.201.192.101:467  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond 173.201.192.101:467
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: It does not send the mail. I get an error screen. Do i need to purchase teh capibility form godaddy or what?

Comment: please edit your question and post the error.

Comment: @CsharpBeginner Can you confirm that `relay-hosting.secureserver.net` is the address of the target mailserver? That hostname doesn't even respond to pings...

Comment: would that be this:   

Incoming server (POP3):
 pop.secureserver.net 
110, 995 (SSL)




Outgoing server (SMTP):
 smtpout.secureserver.net 
80, 3535, 25, 465 (SSL)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked to Godaddy Customer Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this and it works. Code is below for others having the same issue.

```
  try
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net"))
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("godaddyemail", "pw");


                //client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; 
                //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 

                string to = "send email to who";


                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                mail.From = new MailAddress("mygodaddyemail", "subject");
                mail.To.Add(to);



                mail.Subject = "New member Alert";
                mail.Body = "New member ";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                client.Send(mail);
                return "sent mail";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception handling 
            return ex.ToString();
        }
```